# How to show image instead of text in WebGrid header

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor, webgrid

I am trying to use the WebGrid in My MVC 4 application and in my grid I want to display images in header .So please give some example for this, how can I achieve this. I tried searching on internet but didn't get any feasible solution.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried and succeeded showing image by replacing the header text with image using jQuery
Here is my Code Hope it helps someone . Thanks

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".webgrid-table th").each(function () {
        var text = $(this).text().trim();
        if (text == "TotalEmail") {
            $(this).html('<img src="/Images/circles.jpg"/>');
        }
    });
});
```

Vote Up if you find this answer usefull !